# Line Spacing in the Title (in .cls file)

Tags: titles, line-spacing

I am trying to insert some line spacing in the title of a document. The .cls file has the following code:

```
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge\expandafter{\@title}} \\[3.5cm]
        By \\[3.5cm]
        \textbf{\@author}\\
    \end{center}
```

How to ensure that the line spacing is there if the title expands to two lines?

Comment: Hi. This has surely been asked before: `{\Huge...\par} \vspace{3.5cm}`. I'm not sure why `\expandafter` there, I don't see why it would be necessary.